# converting text size into data coordinates

Tags: python, matplotlib

In matplotlib, what is a way of converting the text box size into data coordinates? 
For example, in this toy script I'm fine-tuning the coordinates of the text box so that it's next to a data point.

```
#!/usr/bin/python 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xx=[1,2,3]
yy=[2,3,4]
dy=[0.1,0.2,0.05]

fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.errorbar(xx,yy,dy,fmt='ro-',ms=6,elinewidth=4)

# HERE: can one get the text bbox size?
txt=ax.text(xx[1]-0.1,yy[1]-0.4,r'$S=0$',fontsize=16)

ax.set_xlim([0.,3.4])
ax.set_ylim([0.,4.4])

plt.show()
```

Is there a way of doing something like this pseudocode instead?

```
x = xx[1] - text_height
y = yy[1] - text_width/2
ax.text(x,y,text)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not happy with it at all, but the following works; I was getting frustrated until I found [this code](http://gregstoll.dyndns.org/~gregstoll/targetprobs/outputgraph.py.txt) for a similar problem, which suggested a way to get at the renderer.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xx=[1,2,3]
yy=[2,3,4]
dy=[0.1,0.2,0.05]

fig=plt.figure()
figname = "out.png"
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.errorbar(xx,yy,dy,fmt='ro-',ms=6,elinewidth=4)

# start of hack to get renderer
fig.savefig(figname)
renderer = plt.gca().get_renderer_cache()
# end of hack

txt = ax.text(xx[1], yy[1],r'$S=0$',fontsize=16)
tbox = txt.get_window_extent(renderer)
dbox = tbox.transformed(ax.transData.inverted())
text_width = dbox.x1-dbox.x0
text_height = dbox.y1-dbox.y0
x = xx[1] - text_height
y = yy[1] - text_width/2
txt.set_position((x,y))

ax.set_xlim([0.,3.4])
ax.set_ylim([0.,4.4])

fig.savefig(figname)
```

OTOH, while this might get the text box out of the actual data *point*, it doesn't necessarily get the box out of the way of the *marker*, or the error bar.  So I don't know how useful it'll be in practice, but I guess it wouldn't be that hard to loop over all the drawn objects and move the text until it's out of the way.  I think the linked code tries something similar.

Edit: Please note that this was clearly a courtesy accept; I would use Joe Kington's solution if I actually wanted to do this, and so should everyone else. :^)

Comment: Wow, that's a cool one! In my particular case annotate() does the job, as Joe pointed out, but your trick is just so cool. Thanks a-gazillion!

Answer (score 11):

Generally speaking, you can't get the size of the text until after it's drawn (thus the hacks in @DSM's answer).

For what you're wanting to do, you'd be far better off using [annotate](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/annotations.html).

E.g. `ax.annotate('Your text string', xy=(x, y), xytext=(x-0.1, y-0.4))`

Note that you can specify the offset in *points* as well, and thus offset the text by it's height (just specify `textcoords='offset points'`)

If you're wanting to adjust vertical alignment, horizontal alignment, etc, just add those as arguments to `annotate` (e.g. `horizontalalignment='right'` or equivalently `ha='right'`)